# Fabric.js: disable deselection

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need to disable deselection of a selected object in Fabric.js 1.7.19. I tried:

```
  object.on('deselected', function(e) {
    canvas.setActiveObject(object);
  });
```

This seems to do the job, but removal of a selected object doesn't work: remove() triggers 'deselected' as well, leading to some bad behaviour.

As for the onDeselect() callback mentioned in the docs, I can't seem to get it to work. Could someone help me with an example?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gl03/khwmk4yx/

Comment: just add `if(canvas._objects.length)` before `setActiveObject` if you have more than two object you can add `if(find(canvas._objects,image))`

Comment: thank you, @artgb - `if(canvas._objects.length)`works, but i have more than one object. `if(find(canvas._objects,image))` doesn't work, it still allows deselection. [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gl03/4bvb8ofz/1/)

Comment: Please see https://jsfiddle.net/4bvb8ofz/2/ defined `find` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the object is existing in `canvas._objects` array.

```
function find(objs, obj){
    for (var i = 0; i< objs.length; i++)
      if(objs[i] == obj) return 1;
  return 0;
} 
 image.on('deselected', function(e) {
    if(find(canvas._objects,image)) {
      console.log('deselected');
      canvas.setActiveObject(image);
     }
 });
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/4bvb8ofz/2/